# SQL Server 2008 R2 Job Launched Step 1 hundreds of times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

I have an ETL SSIS package that is scheduled via job to run nightly at 7pm. It is the only step in the job, and the failure action is "quit the job reporting failure". The server is Windows Server 2008 R2, and the SQL Server version is 2008 R2. There is also an instance of SQL Server 2012 installed on this server, but the services are not started for that instance.

I've made no changes to the job, package, or server, and tonight it behaved strangely. When I look at the history of the job and expand tonight, it shows starting step 1 over 400 times, all at exactly 7 PM. It looks like it just kept launching it until the transaction log filled the entire drive and had no more space to grow, then exited the job reporting failure. I shrunk the transaction log by setting recovery mode to simple and running DBCC SHRINKFILE. I then restarted all of the SQL services for that instance and re-ran the job. So far, it seems to be running as expected, although I suppose time will tell.

I did a search of stack overflow and have seen nothing like this mentioned. We're actually starting a project to virtualize the box, then upgrade to 2012, so this may end up being one of those oddball things that never happens again, but I thought I'd ask in case anyone has any idea why this might have happened.

Comment: there is no information here that would enable a diagnosis.

Comment: Please share with me what further information you require.

Answer (score 0):

open the job step and go to the advanced tab. Look at the retry attempts. could it be that it has a big number? this would make the step run many times if it fails.
:[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I should have added that in - I checked that too, retry attempts set to 0. Also, if it was retrying, wouldn't they all have different start times? They all start at exactly 7:00:00 PM

Comment: Done - sorry I'm new and still figuring out the stack overflow etiquette :)